# Passing data from Controller to View using JSon object

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following to get the Json abject passed from the controller and populate the various textboxes in the view. However, nothing is happening even though controller is passing a valid Json object. What is wrong with this code???

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {
     var url = '<%=Url.Action("DropDownChange") %>';
     $("#vendorID").change(function() {
         var selectedID = $(this).val();
         if (selectedID != "New Vendor Id") {
             //$.post('Url.Action("DropDownChange","Refunds")', function(result) {
             $.post(url, { dropdownValue: selectedID }, function(result) {
                 alert(selectedID);
                 $("#name").val(result.Name);
                 $("#city").val(result.City);
                 $("#contact").val(result.Contact);
                 $("#address2").val(result.Address2);
                 $("#address1").val(result.Address1);
                 $("#state").val(result.State);
                 $("#zip").val(result.Zip);

             });

         }
     });

 });
```

This is the code in my controller;

```
public JsonResult DropDownChange(string dropdownValue)
    // This action method gets called via an ajax request   
    {


        if (dropdownValue != null && Request.IsAjaxRequest() == true)
        {

            paymentApplicationRefund  =
            cPaymentRepository.PayableEntity(dropdownValue);

            paymentApplicationRefund.Address1.Trim();
            paymentApplicationRefund.Address2.Trim();
            paymentApplicationRefund.Name.Trim();
            paymentApplicationRefund.City.Trim();
            paymentApplicationRefund.Contact.Trim();
            paymentApplicationRefund.State.Trim();
            paymentApplicationRefund.Zip.Trim();

            return Json(paymentApplicationRefund,"application/json");               
        }

        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see no errors - I am using firebug for IE.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to tell it to expect JSON data back.  By default it assumes it's HTML.

```
$.post(url, { dropdownValue: selectedID }, function(result) {
              alert(selectedID);
              $("#name").val(result.Name);
              $("#city").val(result.City);
              $("#contact").val(result.Contact);
              $("#address2").val(result.Address2);
              $("#address1").val(result.Address1);
              $("#state").val(result.State);
              $("#zip").val(result.Zip);
           }, 'json');
```

Comment: based on what I have here - are there any other possible approaches I could take?

Comment: @Jam - Have you looked at the response using Firebug to see what data is actually sent? and to ensure that the request is being made?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer sending Json to a ActionResult with my DTO as the parameter and use the [JsonValueProviderFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonvalueproviderfactory%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) do the deserialization for me.

[Sending JSON to an ASP.NET MVC Action Method Argument](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
Add the ".change()" at the end of the function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
   var url = '<%=Url.Action("DropDownChange") %>';
   $("#vendorID").change(function() {          
   .....
   }).change();
});
```